# Update query executing but not updating table

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I am having difficulties using the UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause

I am using the following code to try to update a record in the table WHERE squadnumber is the value in the squadnumber dropdown.

```
<img src="header.png" alt="Southside FC Header">
<h1>Player Statistics</h1> 

<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    //initial query
    $query = "UPDATE playerstatistics SET squadnumber=':squadnumber', appearances=':appearances', subappearances=':subappearances', 
    goalsscored=':goalsscored', yellowcards=':yellowcards', redcards=':redcards' WHERE squadnumber=':squadnumber'";

    //Update query
    $query_params = array(
        ':squadnumber' => $_POST['squadnumber'],
        ':appearances' => $_POST['appearances'],
        ':subappearances' => $_POST['subappearances'],
        ':goalsscored' => $_POST['goalsscored'],
        ':yellowcards' => $_POST['yellowcards'],
        ':redcards' => $_POST['redcards']

    );


    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        header('Location: http://localhost/webservice/errorCouldNotAddData.php');
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    header('Location: http://localhost/webservice/managerhomepage.php');
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {


?>
<br /> 

<form action="addplayerstatistic.php" method="post">

Squad Number: <br />
<select name="squadnumber">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
</select>
<br />

Number of appearances:<br /> 
<input type="number" name="appearances"/><br />

Number of appearances as a substitute:<br /> 
<input type="number" name="subappearances"/><br />

Number of Goals Scored:<br /> 
<input type="number" name="goalsscored"/><br />

Number of yellow cards:<br /> 
<input type="number" name="yellowcards"/><br />

Number of red cards:<br /> 
<input type="number" name="redcards"/><br />

<input type="submit" value="Add statistics" /> 
</form>

<a href="managerhomepage.php"><img src="backButton.png"></a>
<?php

}

?>
```

$response["success"] is being set to one as the query appears to have ran correctly, however when I check the database nothing has changed.

I think my problem surrounds the WHERE clause not being set to the number in the dropdown so no row is updated.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `$response['success']=1` is not being set.. **you are setting it**, put it in `try function`....

Comment: You are correct, that was being set in the wrong place. However that isn't the main problem. The problem surrounds the update query and the values within it not being set to those in the dropdown and textfields.

Comment: remove `comments (\\)` from your `die function in try`.. and check what happens..

Comment: Just tried that, it does not die. It still appears to have updated the table even though it has not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your query

```
$query = "UPDATE playerstatistics SET squadnumber=:squadnumber, appearances=:appearances, subappearances=:subappearances, 
goalsscored=:goalsscored, yellowcards=:yellowcards, redcards=:redcards WHERE squadnumber=:squadnumber";
```

You should not escape your parameters - PDO does that for you.